# Servers with same configuration ended up with different kernels

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

I have several `Ubuntu 14.04` servers that have been installed from the same image. Their hardware is identical and they have same Apt sources configured.

I noticed that some of them have kernel of `3.13` series while others have that of `3.16` series. Because of that some of them are getting warning of HWE stack suppor ending. Those with `3.13` don't have HWE. (I known how to upgrade the HWE that is not problem.)

How is it possible that some of the servers have got HWE and newer kernel? They have only been updated with `apt-get dist-upgrade` and no manual installation of newer kernels have been done. From `Apts` log I can see that the 3.16 kernels got installed after issuing `apt-get distupgrade`command. Other servers never got 3.16 tought the installation command was the same.

`Apt-get` update was always executed before upgrading.

The servers have been updated at different times. (Sometimes even on different month). And sometimes they have been up few months without rebooting. now I have rebooted all servers and the difference remains. Those with 3.13 don't get offered to install 3.16 kernels.

What could have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Those server that have the 3.16 kernels were installed from 14.04.2 ISO image. It initially had the 3.16 kernel.